# Splitting Nomex FPC Jumpers

Tags: fpc

I have been splitting PTFE FPC jumpers using an Exacto knife and that works fine, but the Nomex FPC connectors are cheaper. The PTFE is a tough, but pliable, homogeneous material so cuts just fine with straight, clean lines. But my understanding is Nomex is a kevlar-like material (difficult to cut and has fibers in it so does not cut cleanly).

Has anyone handled Nomex FPC jumpers to get a feel whether it can be cut by a knife?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a high quality set of miniature scissors/shears like https://www2.fiskars.com/Products/Crafting-and-Sewing/Scissors-and-Shears/RazorEdge-Micro-Tip-Easy-Action-Shears-6 or https://www.excelta.com/standard-kevlar-scissors ?

Comment: @pericynthion No, but I don't have the FPC in hand and wanted to check before wasting money on them.

Comment: Makes sense, hopefully someone has direct experience with cutting that type of FPC. I don't, but I've had success using those tools to cut materials that sound similar to your description of the nomex.